# Auto create XML header for C# files using Resharper 2016.1

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, comments, resharper

Is there any way to automate Resharper to add function headers to all C# functions?

Eg

```
/// <summary />
/// <param name="path"></param>
/// <param name="logError"></param>
public FileFormatPluginLoader(string path, Action<string, Exception, bool> logError = null)
```

If I type /// at least once, then run Code Cleanup (Ctrl+e,c) it will create these. I would like it to also automate the initial /// step for functions with no XML header at all.

Is this possible with Resharper? Or do I require a third party program/script?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any ReSharper plugins that do this, but you may want to look at [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) which will do this and more for you.

GhostDoc analyzes method signatures and generates very basic documentation based on it. So you don't even need to type `///`.